# Can the multiple context pattern prevent rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm currently doing research on how to manage global state. One pattern that seems to be popular is the multiple context pattern:

```
export default function makeStore<State, Actions = string>(
    reducer: Reducer<State, Actions>,
    initalState: State
): [
    ({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) => JSX.Element,
    () => Dispatch<Actions>,
    () => State
] {
    const dispatchContext = createContext<Dispatch<Actions>>(() => null);
    const storeContext = createContext<State>(initalState);

    const StoreProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) => {
        const [store, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<State, Actions>>(
            reducer,
            initalState
        );

        return (
            <dispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                <storeContext.Provider value={store}>
                    {children}
                </storeContext.Provider>
            </dispatchContext.Provider>
        );
    };

    function useDispatch() {
        return useContext(dispatchContext);
    }

    function useStore() {
        return useContext(storeContext);
    }

    return [StoreProvider, useDispatch, useStore];
}
```

The idea here is, that separating `dispatch` and `state` into their own contexts can somehow avoid unnecessary rerenders. By using `useDispatch` or `useState` components can "subscribe" to only state or dispatch. After working with this for a minute or two, I found myself wondering how this pattern can have any effect on rerendering at all.

As far as I know, whenever the state changes, React will rerender everything below the providers. The effect that separating `dispatch` into their own contexts can have on e. g. the dependency arrays of hooks (making renders more performant) should also be negligible since dispatch is a stable value across renders.

**Is there any advantage that comes from using this pattern vs using just one context?**

Answer (score -1):

The trick here is to not only separate the store and dispatch into separate contexts but also the components utilizing them .

This pattern is not effective when you have the component which dispatches an action and also consumes the store value. Even though `dispatch` will not trigger a re-render but since the component is consuming the value from the store it will re-render .

So if you isolate the components which `dispatches` the action from the components consuming it then this pattern will be effective .

Also wrap the component which is using `dispatch` from the context with the React.memo to avoid re-rendering . Because `useReducer` guarantees that the reference of `dispatch` will not change between re-renders.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

Comment: Hm, this is how redux works since you can "subscribe" to the store (or only parts of the store). To my knowledge, this is not how context works. My understanding is that when the context value changes reference the entire subtree is rerendered. This includes components using only dispatch as well as only using the store value.

Comment: updated my answer , you also need to use `React.memo` as well .